# how could deploy backup keystone service across multiple region

Tags: backup, openstack

In my situation, there are three Openstack clusters deployed at three different cities which called regionA, regionB and regionC.

- We use the one keystone service which is only deployed in regionA.
- Now we should deploy the keystone backup service at regionC, this regionC keystone is only for backup or using while regionA keystone shutdown.

How could I achieve that?

In my opinion, we should deploy the databases like MariaDB and [Keystone](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/getting-started/architecture.html) service at regionC, but I can't figure out how to do, this reference "[Multiple Regions Deployment with Kolla](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/rocky/user/multi-regions.html)" can't solve my problem

Comment: I don't use multiple regions and I'm not familiar with kolla, but the general idea is described [here](https://object-storage-ca-ymq-1.vexxhost.net/swift/v1/6e4619c416ff4bd19e1c087f27a43eea/www-assets-prod/presentation-media/slides.pdf). There are also a couple of interesting videos from openstack summit out there which talk about multi-region deployments. Basically, the database is a galera cluster which replicates between regions.